# Laravel validation unique soft deleted

Tags: php, laravel

I have an input in my DB that is soft deleted and if the user tries to create a new input with same name he will get a validation error "name already exists"

What is the best practice to solve this?

Is it better to leave it so because maybe the soft deleted entry will be restored which would cause a conflict (if i would somehow make it work so that the user can insert a new entry with the same name)

I don't know what is the right thing to do, but I'm sure that I'm not the only one who had this situation.

Comment: Do you really need soft deleting? As in REALLY need? There are ways around this "bug" and I'll gladly give them, but in my experience soft deleting has broken more software than it fixed.

Comment: Well, soft deletion is not my call...but i would like to know more about that...why is soft deleting a bad practice?

Comment: It's not necessarily a bad practice. If you have a lot of records with high chance of restoration need after they were deleted, soft deleting is your best friend. But in my experience the only reason for soft deleting is because people just want to keep their data, in which case you should dump your database once per day/week/whatever and it's perfectly fine to forgo soft deleting. This is an interesting artice, with good comments too! Read them and figure out what you should do :) http://jameshalsall.co.uk/posts/why-soft-deletes-are-evil-and-what-to-do-instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use case should ideally govern your entire architecture.

If you want your column (say name) to be unique, you would add a unique index to the column in your **table structure** and you would also add a validation to check for duplicates in your **controller**.

In my opinion, if you have a soft deletion and your use case requires your column to be unique, then you must add the validation (otherwise there would be a violation on inserts in your DB)

> You don't have a choice

.